# Dynamically select an object from several imports with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, import

I'm coding a web app in JS with Webpack. In the preferences of the app, the user can select its favorite sound.

I import all the sounds with the following:

```
import pop1 from "Assets/sounds/right/pop-1.mp3";
import pop2 from "Assets/sounds/right/pop-2.mp3";
import tic from "Assets/sounds/right/tic.mp3";
import toc from "Assets/sounds/right/toc.mp3";
...
```

I have dozen of sounds. I would like to write a function that select the sound, something like:

```
setSound("pop1");
```

The parameter of the function is a string, so I have to write something like:

```
setSound
{
  eval (`this.favoriteSound = ${name};`;
}
```

or

```
setSound
{
  switch (name) {
    case "pop1": this.favoriteSound = pop1; break;
    case "pop2": this.favoriteSound = pop2; break;
    case "tic": this.favoriteSound = tic; break;
    case "toc": this.favoriteSound = toc; break;
    ....
  }
}
```

I'm not satisfied by both solutions (I avoid using `eval()` and the `switch` is not generic).

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Try webpack's [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext). Example should match all the `.mp3/.wav/.m4a` files in the directory.

```
function importAll(r) {
  return r.keys().reduce((acc, key) => {
    const k = key.replace("./", "");
    return {
      ...acc,
      [k]: r(key),
    };
  }, {});
}

const sounds = importAll(require.context("Assets/sounds/right/", false, /\.(mp3|wav|m4a)$/));
```

```
// Usage
function setSound(name) {
  this.favoriteSound = sounds[name];
}
setSound("pop-1.mp3");
```

If you wish, you can also update the `importAll` function, to remove the extensions `.mp3`.

Comment: Thx, sounds great but it does not work : `sounds["tic"]` or `sound["tic.mp3"]`  are undefined. But `sounds[0]` returns a module

Comment: Updated my code, should import the module via `sounds["toc.mp3"]` now.

Comment: I get the sounds array `sounds[]` with the right labels. But when I try to play a sound, I get the following error : `failed to load because no supported source was found.`

Comment: I created a new question, since this may be another issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76321774/mp3-files-loaded-with-webpack-require-context-wont-play