# mp3 files loaded with Webpack / require.context() won't play

Tags: javascript, webpack

I'm coding a web app in JS with Webpack. In the preferences of the app, the user can select its favorite sound. I have dozen of sounds.  Based on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76318117/dynamically-select-an-object-from-several-imports-with-webpack), I load the mp3 files with the following code

```
function importAllSounds(r) {
  return r.keys().reduce((acc, key) => {
    const k = key.replace("./", "").replace(".mp3", "");
    return {
      ...acc,
      [k]: r(key),
    };
  }, {});
}

const sounds = importAllSounds(require.context("Assets/sounds/right/", false, /\.(mp3|wav|m4a)$/));
```

When I try to play a sound:

```
let audio = new Audio(sounds["tic"]);
    
document.addEventListener("keydown", () => {  
  audio.play();  
})
```

I've got the following error:

> sound.js:40 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources

When I `console.log (sounds['tic'])`:

```
default: (...)
__esModule: true
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"
get default: () => (__WEBPACK_DEFAULT_EXPORT__)
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Comment: what `console.log(sounds["tic"])` print?

Comment: @nhy I updated the question with the answer

Comment: according to this [document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio). 
`new Audio(url)` only accept url as a `An optional string containing the URL of an audio file to be associated with the new audio element.` We need another approach. Can you log out value of the above `default`

Comment: So what you trying to do is to dynamic import a audio file using webpack?

Comment: It works properly if I import the mp3 files individually with Webpack without `require.context()`. My purpose is explained at the beginning of the question

Comment: What loader are you using for mp3 files in `webpack`, I tried locally with `asset/resource` loader and works for me. https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

Comment: I'm using `url-loader` to get the mp3 files encapsulated in the bundle

Comment: Try instead using `asset/inline` instead of `url-loader`. I tried both and both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option A:**

Change `url-loader` to the newer `asset/inline`. https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/

**Option B:**

Update the `importAllSounds` function to:

```
function importAllSounds(r) {
  return r.keys().reduce((acc, key) => {
    const k = key.replace("./", "").replace(".mp3", "");
    return {
      ...acc,
      [k]: r(key).default,
    };
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: You are f**ing awesome ! Thxs